# php -f executes script from page but accessing web page does not?

Tags: php, mysql

My problem is that i don't have any proper explanation for this happening.

When i run the php file with the script in it using run command `php -f "file"` it executes properly.

When i run it via webpage, it does not, i have to manually run it via command line first to get web page results.

I have tried using the old and new `php` tags as i found such a suggestion but doesn't help, all other like pages run fine.

Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: stupid me, on server i had root privileges for file i was editing via script, on webpage i did not, gave the right permissions, all works ))

Answer (score 0):

stupid me, on server i had root privileges for file i was editing via script, on webpage i did not, gave the right permissions, all works ))